# PHP HTML table retrieve multiple data in one <td> tag

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to generate a list from database in a HTML table just like image below;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/61XLl.png

And here's what i did;

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLsvF.png

And the code;

```
    <table cellpadding="3" border="1"  style="width:100%;margin-top:30px; margin-bottom:50px; font-size:12px">
    <thead>      
        <tr>
            <th>KURSUS</th>
            <th rowspan="2">NAMA PENSYARAH</th>
            <th rowspan="2">NO. SIRI</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <th>NAMA</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody align="center">
        <?php
            if($numrow>0)
            {
                while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()){

                    $code=explode("/",$row['po_code']);
                    $list=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM polist WHERE polist_poid='".$row['po_id']."' ORDER BY polist_bil ASC");
                    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['po_name']; ?></td>
            <?php while($rowlist = $list->fetch_assoc()){ 

                    $name=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='".$rowlist['polist_userid']."'");
                    $rowname=$name->fetch_array();?>
            <td><?php echo $rowname['user_name']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $code[0]."/PO/".$code[1]." - ".$rowlist['polist_bil']; ?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>

                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Help me. Thank you in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code. Concat user names and code with "br" tags in the second while loop and display them in "tds" after while loop.

```
<tbody align="center">
        <?php
            if($numrow>0)
            {
                while($row = $select->fetch_assoc()){

                    $code=explode("/",$row['po_code']);
                    $list=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM polist WHERE polist_poid='".$row['po_id']."' ORDER BY polist_bil ASC");
                    ?>

        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $row['po_name']; ?></td>
            <?php
                $user_names = $codes = '';  // define empty variables
                while($rowlist = $list->fetch_assoc()){ 

                    $name=$connect->query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE user_id='".$rowlist['polist_userid']."'");
                    $rowname=$name->fetch_array();
                    $user_names .= $rowname['user_name']."<br/>"; //concat to a single string
                    $codes .= $code[0]."/PO/".$code[1]." - ".$rowlist['polist_bil']."<br/>"; //concat to a single string
            }?>
            <td><?php echo $user_names;?></td>
            <td><?php echo $codes;?></td>
        </tr>

                    <?php
                }
            }
        ?>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the `<td>` outside the `<?php while($rowlist = $list->fetch_assoc()){`

Or get all your data before you start display html and store it in a multi-dimensional array. Then simply loop through the data array. That way you won't have as much php mixed with html also.